# Rails where with many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :product_categories

end

class ProductCategory < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

I have an array of Product Categories and i need to select all the Proudcts that belongs to one of the categories in the array

Thanks, Rotem

Comment: sth like that? `product_categories.each { |pr|  pr.products }`

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

`ProductCategory.first.products`

will list all products belongs to first product category.